# CSS on PDF (Prawn)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Can we use stylesheet classes inside Pdf reports?

i am trying to change the header_color from b7e3fe to .heading oh the stylesheet, inside the table

file:heading.pdf.prawn

texts=[""],[""]

```
pdf.table texts,

    :headers => ["     Heading "],

:header_color => 'b7e3fe',
```

file: public/stylesheets/style.css

.heading

```
{ font-family: "trebuchet ms", Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;   font-size: 11px; background: #E5E5E5;  color: #0D0E0E; font-weight: bold;  padding-left:10px; line-height: 20px;}
```

Comment: CSS is for HTML only. Period.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use HTML/CSS to generate PDFs, you should look at [PDFKit](http://github.com/jdpace/PDFKit) instead of Prawn.